# Синтаксис python

Tags: python, list, for, range

Я хочу задать список из значений произведения трёхзначных чисел, которые являются палиндромами.
Вот так я вижу свою реализацию в одну строчку, но почему-то этот способ не работает. Он не выводит никаких ошибок, но список получается пустым.

```
a = [(i * j)for i in range(100, 999) for j in range (100, 999) if str(i * j) == reversed(str(i * j)) ]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в такую конструкцию загнать цикл в цикле.

Comment: `str(i * j) == "".join(reversed(str(i * j))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
a = [
    (i * j) 
    for i in range(100, 999) 
    for j in range(100, 999) 
    if list(str(i * j)) == list(reversed(str(i * j)))
]
```

Проблема вашего кода была только в том, что вы сравнивали строку с объектом `reversed`. Нужно просто привести оба типа к списку (т.к. к строке `reversed` не приводится)